# i use npm run dev why can'y find vuejs

Tags: vue.js, webpack

npm run dev Why can't I find the referenced vue.js
only app.js

[image]

Comment: dev mode bundle all in one js by default

Comment: take a look into your `package.json -> scripts`. Does `dev` exist at all? or do you have to use `npm run serve`?